# Downgrade from SQL 2005 Enterprise to 2005 Standard on a clustered server

Tags: sql-server

Can anybody help with downgrade Ent to Standard on a cluster. We have no place to test, so we want to make sure we get everything right.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can downgrade to a lesser version.  You have to do a new installation of SQL Server 2005 standard.  If you are OK with named instances this shouldn't be an issue.  You can install a new named instance on the same server with Enterprise assuming that Enterprise is the default instance.  Then there are number of methods you can use to get your Databases, Jobs, SSISpackages, etc. over to the standard instance assuming your not using any Enterprise specific features that are not supported by standard.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Enterprise edition is different by design from SQL standard edition but in 10 steps, here's a straight forward way to avoid expensive work and the lengthy error fixing in case one comes up:

Request for downtime like 3-5 hours for this exercise depending on how fast your server is, then go ahead and perform the following tasks.
1. Take users off your application & ensure that all transactions are complete.
2. If you have many jobs that run frequently, simply stop SQL server agent so that nothing starts up automatically while you're trying to make major changes.
3. Do a full database backup of your production databases, verify backups after. This is a good practice. Checking database integrity (data & index linkage) before backing up will show you the state of your database, hence reducing the risk of losing your data.
4. If you want, script out your jobs and logins (use a procedure sp_help_revlogin from Microsoft for logins).
5. Note the path of your production database files first, then detach your production databases.
6. User database files are not deleted by uninstalling. Therefore uninstall the SQL Enterprise instance, restart the operating system.
7. Install SQL Standard. I recommend you to apply the latest service pack at this point. A restart might be required.
8. Note that user databases from an Enterprise SQL instance can be managed by one running SQL Standard. So, go ahead and attach the production databases.
9. Viola!  Now you have an SQL Standard instance running your production databases.
10. If you scripted your jobs and logins, run your scripts to re-create them on the newly installed instance otherwise manually create logins and write your agent jobs.

--As answered in SSC. Hope this should be the same for Cluster too since you are not restoring system databases because you are going to script those settings.

Comment: Would it be possible to use mirroring to switch from Enterprise to Standard?  I assume not, but I thought I would ask.